# How To select limited number of rows from procedure out cursor

Tags: plsql

i have a cursor out from a procedure..and i want to fetch particular rows.. i.e, i want to use where condition in that out cursor..can we do the same in PL/SQL develover 10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the cursor has been opened, its result set is determined, so you cannot filter it then.  If you cannot have the required filter added into the procedure definition then you are going to have to fetch all the rows and filter them in your code.

Comment: thanks...tony ..but my problem is i am reusing that procedure..so i cant give filter condition in the procedure...so acoording to you i have to fetch all the rows and have to reframe out cursor according to the requirement... :)

Comment: Perhaps the procedure could be parameterised to perform the filtering only when needed?  But I know sometimes the procedure you are calling as outside your control and the owner won't change it (particlarly in SOA projects...)  In such cases you are, I'm afraid, forced to fetch all the rows and process them.